# Regarding if conditions and || operator in C++

Tags: c++

So I didn't write the below piece of code. I came across it, and am curious as to how the if condition is evaluated.

```
if(a==b || c || d || e)
```

I think it just checks if a==b and the rest of the code is meaningless. Am i right? does the c,d,e have any meaning? Another side question, what does this evaluate?

```
if(a == (b || c || d || e))
```

I'm not very experienced in C++

Comment: The rest of the code is not meaningless. It is evaluated if `a!=b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not meaningless. It checks if `a==b`, if they are not equal then it checks if `c` is true or not, if it is not then it checks if `d` is true or not, if it is not then it checks if `e` if true or not. Overall the expression is true if any one of the four subexpressions is true.

Comment: c,d,e a re just variables

Comment: @rainman_s So? Variables can still be checked to see if they are true or not.

Comment: Really? So what will they evaluate to?

Comment: Yes, but how does it determine if a variable is true or false? does 0 = true and anything else = false? I guess it would also depend to some extent on the compiler

Comment: @memo1288 it can be false in other conditions too. It depends on its type.

Comment: @rainman_s surely whatever resource you are using to learn C++ tells you that?

Comment: @rainman_s It does not depend on the compiler it depends on the rules of C++. I think you need a textbook.

Comment: @memo1288 I've always thought 0 = true. You sure about 0=false?

Comment: @rainman_s Both of you are wrong, although you are more wrong than memo1288. This is getting tiresome.

Comment: Then can you please explain how it determines if a variable is evaluated as true or false?

Comment: @rainman_s It's complicated, there are many rules, but the first thing to understand is the type of the variable makes a big difference. There are `bool` variables these just **are** true or false. Then there are various kinds of integer variables, memo1288 was right about that, 0 is false, other values are true, then there are pointer variables, NULL is false, others are true, then there are floating point variables, then there are user defined types. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say the remaining arguments are meaningless because if (a != b), than the other arguments will be evaluated. However it is true as far as I know that if (a == b) is evaluated as true, than the remaining arguments will not be evaluated because that would be unnecessary.

Remember though that this the case for any 'OR' or '||' conditional statement, which returns true if just one argument is true. Therefore, any conditional statement using 'OR', will evaluate as true if the first argument is true, without having to evaluate the remaining arguments.